# juniper srx - basic routing/transparent mode

Tags: networking

juniper firefly + basic static route in gns3.

Configuration is smilar in:
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB21421

I'm delete untrunt zone:

```
root# run show configuration 
## Last commit: 2015-07-27 20:32:29 UTC by root
version 12.1X47-D20.7;
system {
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "$1$HtKID/TF$jteDsW8F17nSgIQj5e6KF0"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family bridge {
                interface-mode access;
                vlan-id 10;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family bridge {
                interface-mode access;
                vlan-id 10;
            }
        }
    }                                   
    irb {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 172.27.186.63/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0 next-hop 172.27.186.1
    }
}
security {
    policies {
        from-zone trust to-zone trust {
            policy 1 {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }                       
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
bridge-domains {
    test {                              
        domain-type bridge;
        vlan-id 10;
        routing-interface irb.0;
    }
}
```

ping 172.27.186.2->172.27.186.3 not work
ping 172.27.186.3->172.27.186.2 not work

ping 172.27.186. 2 or 3 -> 172.27.186.63 work.

I spent several hours and I do not see where the place is a problem.
This is a simple configuration to learn the rules and theoretically should work, but it is not.
Someone will say where is the error?

I made myself a static routing between 2 cisco routers - ping worked, I added between routers juniper-a and set similarly to the above is unfortunately also not working.

It does not operate even such a simple routing, where there are 2 commands:
   youtube.com / watch?v=I9li31WvUA8

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to set up default security policy to "permit-all":

> ```
> security {
>     policies {
>         default-policy {
>             permit-all;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Try to create Security Zones if you haven't created it yet:

> ```
> security {
>     zones {
>         security-zone Internal {
>             interfaces {
>                 ge-0/0/0.0 {
>                     host-inbound-traffic {
>                         system-services {
>                             ping;
>                             ssh;
>                             telnet;
>                             all;
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>                 [...]
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```